# Error on WiringPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, twisted

I'm trying to set the outputs of my raspberry through twisted in this mode

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

import smbus
import sys
import getopt
import time
import os
import signal

bus = smbus.SMBus(0)
import wiringpi2 as wiringpi
from time import sleep

class Raspi(Protocol):
  def connectionMade(self):  
     print("A client connected")
  def dataReceived(self, data):

if data == "s1":

 pin_base = 65       
 i2c_addr = 0x20     
 wiringpi.wiringPiSetup()                    
 wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(pin_base,i2c_addr)   
 wiringpi.pinMode(65, 1)           
 sleep (0.3) 
 #

elif data == "s2”:

  pin_base = 65       
  i2c_addr = 0x20     
  wiringpi.wiringPiSetup()                    
  wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(pin_base,i2c_addr)   
  wiringpi.pinMode(65, 0)         
  sleep (0.3)
  #
  else:
  stop()

  # Init and start server
  factory = Factory()
  factory.protocol = MovingRaspi
  reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory, 50, '192.168.0.3')
  reactor.run()
```

but if i set s1 and then s2 i have this error in the WiringPi

wiringPiNewNode: Pin 65 overlaps with existing definition

Comment: Your code is mangled – for one thing, it's indented incorrectly – which will make it hard to answer the question.  Your question also isn't very clear.  Is anything else running at the same time?

Comment: No i set for first s1 and then s2

Comment: Or how to rum i .py with twisted ?

Comment: Your code is still broken.  Please edit it to be syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

- Perhaps the `wiringpiSetup()` method is intended to be called only once per run ?
- Perhaps you could try to "cleanup" port after output mode: set it as input before calling `wiringPiSetup()` or `mcp23017Setup()`.

Source: [How to use WiringPi2 for Python on the Raspberry Pi in Raspbian part 1 #Clean up after yourself](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-wiringpi2-for-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-in-raspbian)